# Xcode 6 Memory Leaks Instrument doesn't work

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, xcode6, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am trying to use Instruments to find leaks within my app. I do it in the same way as I did before updating to Xcode 6.x. Since updating, it won't take any snapshots: the *leaks* instrument status displays "Analyzing process" and will never change.

Both Xcode 6.0.1 and 6.1 GM 2 exhibit this problem.

Any workaround?

Comment: PS:I used developer profile.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. I tried the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994264/xcode-instruments-unable-to-take-snapshots-of-leaks-when-running-on-device but nothing worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same problem. And no luck

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: I think this is a bug, I reported it to Apple. I suggest everybody [does the same](http://bugreport.apple.com) so they expedite a fix. It's really inconvenient not being able to debug memory leaks.

Comment: Submitted a bug report. Let's see what they say.

Comment: I got an update yesterday and the bug is not fixed yet. any luck anyone?

Comment: Is this still happening with xcode 6.2 and ios 8.2?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like is a bug on iOS8 and not on Xcode. I have Xcode6.1 and the memory leak profiler seems to work on iOS7.

As a workaround until Apple fix this (already reported the bug and was marked as duplicate) you can profile your memory leaks using a simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to occur only on my iOS 8.x devices.

I also submitted a bug report but in the meantime I have it working with the following configuration :

- Xcode 6.1
- iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3

This is still a workaround though as you can hardly debug any iOS 8 related feature and analyzing leaks on an old device like that is a real pain.